# How to check if a string contains ALL values from an String Array?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, arraylist

Let's say I have a text and I want to check if the text contains a couple of words.

```
let text: String = "The rain in Spain"
let wordsA: [String] = [ "rain", "Spain" ] // should return true when compared with text
let wordsB: [String] = [ "rain", "Italy" ] // should return false when compared with text
```

What is the shortest, quickest way to check if my text contains ALL of the words?

I know, I can do:

```swift
var result: Bool = true
for word in wordsA {
    result = result && text.contains(word)
}
```

But I was wondering if there is a shorter way that involves using predicates. For instance, to check if the string contains ANY of the words I could do:

```swift
let result: Bool = wordsA.contains(where: text.contains)
```

Is there something similar that results only in true if ALL words are found?

Comment: dont have time to answer, but look up `allSatisfy`

Comment: @Alexander Wow that was quick, I just found it in the suggestions of my IDE, but thanks a lot! I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very simple solution, which is perfect for me:

```swift
let result: Bool = wordsA.allSatisfy(text.contains)
```

This works, but it's not fast like Leo's solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should `enumerateSubstrings` in your string using `byWords` option. It will return only words not a sequence of characters that might be just part of a larger word. Once you have all the words of your string you should create a set and check if it is a superset of your words. Your code should be something like:

---

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var setOfWords: Set<String> {
        var setOfWords: Set<String> = []
        enumerateSubstrings(in: startIndex..., options: .byWords) { word, _, _, _ in
            setOfWords.insert(word!)
        }
        return setOfWords
    }
}
```

---

```
let text = "The rain in Spain"

let wordsA = [ "rain", "Spain" ] // should return true when compared with text
let wordsB = [ "rain", "Italy" ] // should return false when compared with text

let setOfWords = text.setOfWords
setOfWords.isSuperset(of: wordsA)  // true
setOfWords.isSuperset(of: wordsB)  // false
```

---

Without extending StringProtocol:

```
let text = "The rain in Spain"
var setOfWords: Set<String> = []
text.enumerateSubstrings(in: text.startIndex..., options: .byWords) { word, _, _, _ in
    setOfWords.insert(word!)
}
let wordsA = [ "rain", "Spain" ]
let wordsB = [ "rain", "Italy" ]

setOfWords.isSuperset(of: wordsA)  // true
setOfWords.isSuperset(of: wordsB)  // false
```

Comment: I learned something new here, although it's definitely too overkill and not what I am after for my current circumstances. I will come back in the future, definitely. I'm pretty sure this will be useful to me one day.

Comment: @MartinBraun using a set is much faster and you don't have to search the string multiple times.

Comment: Sounds right, but is there a way to get rid of the extension to get the thing shorter?

Comment: @MartinBraun sure it would be easy. Note also that your method would return true also for the string "A train in Spain"

Comment: That's a great solution, but I realize that I need to find sub strings of words, too. My implementation is for a search, so I want to match text when matching only a few letters of a word, already. This wasn't very clear in my question, since my sample is using entire words, I'm sorry. Still liking your solution, because it's faster.

Comment: @MartinBraun If you are doing a search you shouldn't use contains. You should use [localizedStandardContains](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416328-localizedstandardcontains) which is diacritic and case insensitive